# editing records in Django Bootstrap Modal window

Tags: javascript, django, python-2.7, django-templates, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to finish a simple application in Django and I need to display some set of data in a modal window, update it and then save. So far I am able to present the selected data in the modal window but my changes do not save. After clicking 'save' button the window closes nicely but the changes are not reflected in the database. The href sits in one file and looks like this:

```
<ul>
{% for n in items %}
    {% if n.status_id != 7 %}
        task:{{ n.task_id }}
    <li><a href="{%  url 'cables.views.add_cycle' id=n.task_id %}" id="link" class="btn btn-default"
           type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{ n.task.sachnr.sachnr }}</a>
        start: {{ n.date_start }} status: {{ n.status.status_set.last.status }} </li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>

<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">

        </div>
    </div>
```

The other file (add_cycle.html) file to which the link follows looks like this:

```
{% block content %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<form action="" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" class="upload">

    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">some header</h4>
<ul>
    <li>sachnr {{ new_cycle.sachnr.sachnr }}</li>
    <li>status: {{ new_cycle.status_set.last.status }} od: {{ new_cycle.status_set.last.date_start }} </li>

</ul>

    <input id="id_status_set-TOTAL_FORMS" name="status_set-TOTAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="1">
    <input id="id_status_set-INITIAL_FORMS" name="status_set-INITIAL_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="id_status_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" name="status_set-MIN_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="0">
    <input id="id_status_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" name="status_set-MAX_NUM_FORMS" type="hidden" value="2">
    <p>
        <label for="id_status_set-0-status">new status:</label>
        <select id="id_status_set-0-status" name="status_set-0-status">
            <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
            {% for n in statuslist %}
            <option value={{ n.id }}>{{ n.name }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
        <input id="id_status_set-0-task" name="status_set-0-task" type="hidden" value="{{ new_cycle.id }}">
        <input id="id_status_set-0-id" name="status_set-0-id" type="hidden" value="{{ status.id }}">
    </p>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">save</button>
    <a href="{% url 'cables_new_task' %}" type="button" class="btn btn-default">cancel</a>
</div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    </form>


</body>
</html>
{% endblock %}
```

When I edit the records without modal window but with a simple link that opens the data in a new tab, everything works fine.

Comment: Why is there no form action in your form?

Comment: Are you using multiple modals? If you have only one, are you updating all inputs including element id?

Comment: You have a form action, or it's a modelForm, or you handle that in js (for the submit). Show us how you handle that. If you have nothing to handle your form, that's normal nothing happen (but the window still close as the click on the button close the window). That's doesn't mean your form's being handled.

Comment: You were right, I was missing action in form. It should be something like action="{% url 'cables_add_cycle' new_cycle.id %}". After adding it, it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You were right, I was missing action in form. It should be something like action="{% url 'cables_add_cycle' new_cycle.id %}". After adding it, it worked just fine.